# Why won't my points (that I created by intersection) intersect with the geometry they've been created from?

Tags: postgis, intersection, splitting

I created a set of points by intersecting a linestring layer with the boundary of a multipolygon layer like this:

```
CREATE TABLE freiraumkataster_grenze AS
SELECT
gid,
ST_CollectionHomogenize(ST_Collect(ST_Boundary(geom))) AS geom
FROM
(SELECT
    gid,
    (ST_Dump(geom)).geom As geom
FROM freiraumkataster fk
) As foo
GROUP BY gid;
```

And

```
CREATE TABLE zugaenge AS
SELECT
w.gid as wgid,
ST_Intersection(w.geom, fkg.geom) as geom
FROM
wegenetz w
LEFT JOIN freiraumkataster_grenze fkg
ON ST_Intersects(w.geom, fkg.geom);
```

Now I try to split the linestrings of `wegenetz` at the location of the points of `zugaenge`. Since they are created on locations where the two layer intersect, this seems to be an easy task.

I read about ST_Split and learned that it has (had?) problems with multigeometries, so I used the (old?) wrapper from here: [Split lines into non-overlapping subsets based on points](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/112282/split-lines-into-non-overlapping-subsets-based-on-points) With the magic:

```
result := input_geom;           
-- Loop on all the points in the blade
FOR simple_blade IN SELECT (ST_Dump(ST_CollectionExtract(blade, 1))).geom
LOOP
    -- keep splitting the previous result
    result := ST_CollectionExtract(ST_Split(result, simple_blade), 2);
END LOOP;
RETURN result;
```

In my (limited) understanding of this, `ST_Split(result, simple_blade)` should work and should produce a geometrycollection containing at least two line strings in the case any intersection is found. But it won't do that. The `result` stays the same single-piece linestring I put into it.

I convert the multipoint layer to singlepoint:

```
CREATE TABLE zugaenge_single AS
SELECT
wgid,
ST_GeometryN(geom, generate_series(1, ST_NumGeometries(geom))) AS geom 
FROM zugaenge;
```

And group them, so there is one multipoint geometry for each linestring.

```
CREATE TABLE zugaenge_pro_weg AS
SELECT wgid, ST_Union(geom) as geom 
FROM zugaenge_single GROUP BY wgid;
```

And then I run the geometries (line string and multipoint) through the wrapper.

```
CREATE TABLE wegenetz_splitted AS
SELECT 
split_line_multipoint(w.geom, z.geom) as geom,
w.gid as wgid
FROM 
wegenetz w
LEFT JOIN 
zugaenge_pro_weg z 
ON w.gid=z.wgid;
```

This results in the same geometry as I find in `wegenetz`, the layer I put into it.

Why is it that way? Why isn't any intersection found? Or do I use any function totally wrong? I even tried to use ST_Split() right away instead of the wrapper, since it should be able to do this task since 2.2, but the result stays the same.

I also tried to enhance the wrapper by using

```
result := ST_CollectionExtract(ST_Split(result, ST_ClosestPoint(result, simple_blade), 2);
```

in case there is a precision problem present. But no change despite a longer run time.

What is it, I can't see?

Comment: Just a thought, since you are creating a number of tables along the way. If you import each of these tables to QGIS you can verify what each step does visually.